# css and media queries not working - newbie with MQ

Tags: css, media-queries

Wow hard to get to work...but new to media queries...

Using angular2 btw...

very simple ...

If min-width: 576px do this, else that....

e.g.

Per the below if 576 then show the menu class and hide the toolbar class and vice versa

```
        <ng-container class="menu" >
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container class="toolbar">
            <span color="accent" style="padding-right: 15px">SolarStack</span>
        </ng-container>
```

Here is my css:

```
/*Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
    .toolbar{
        visibility: collapse;
    }

 }

/*Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .menu{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
 }

/*Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {  
    .menu{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

/*Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 

    .menu{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
 }
```

In essence how to I show or hide elements based on screen size using media queries?  Menu will be shown with iphone and toolbar on desktop

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens..both the toolbar and the menu shows regardless of changing sizes

Comment: Seems like the media queries are working just fine - see fiddle & resize output area. Or if that's not right can you update the question with specifically which bits should be shown/hidden @ which sizes? https://jsfiddle.net/h7vtfyn3/

Comment: What I want to do it like firebase home page -> https://firebase.google.com/  When the browser shrinks then the menu icon shows and the tool bar items are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to set defaults for your class styles which you can then change at a specific screen size, or update your media queries to set styles on any class that changes at that size.

> If min-width: 576px do this:

Meaning that for **everything including & wider than 576**  do:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { 
    .toolbar{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .menu {
        visibility: visible;
    }
 }
```

> else that:

Meaning that for **everything narrower than 576** do:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .toolbar{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .menu {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
 }
```

[In this fiddle, at least](https://jsfiddle.net/pLrovx5t/1/), it appears than **min-width** is inclusive and **max-width** is not. Try changing the width of the output iFrame between 575 & 576.